# removing dictionary item in designer workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, dictionary

How do I remove items from a dictionary created from a REST call in a SP 2013 designer workflow?
I have seen actions for building dictionary and retrieving items but none for removing.

Comment: how you want to remove? Becuase on the same place where you add item in dictionary...You will see the remove button as well...select the item and click remove

Comment: I meant to say I don't see any WF action that would allow me to remove dictionary item. Probably it is not there, but wanted to make sure if I was not missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need the answer to this or not, but you can clear out a dictionary by using the "Set Variable" action. First, you will need to create a new variable of the dictionary type. Leave it blank! When you need to clear out the dictionary that you were using for your REST call, set the REST dictionary to the empty Dictionary.